# When is the support of a module union of some irreducible components?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an module over a ring $A$, define the support of $M$ the set of primes $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$ such that $M_\mathfrak{p}\neq0$. Then I'd like to know what is the relation between the following statements

(i) $M$ is finite flat over $A$.

(ii) $M$ is finite free over $A$

(iii) The support of $M$ is union of some irreducible components of $\mathrm{Spec}A$.

(iv) The set of minimal primes in $\mathrm{Supp}M$ coincides with the set of minimal primes in $\mathrm{Spec}A$.

I’d like to know if (i)$\Longrightarrow$(iii)$\Longrightarrow$(iv) or (ii)$\Longrightarrow$(iii)$\Longrightarrow$(iv) is true.

What I really want to know is under what conditions of M, e.g. finite Cohen-Macaulay, finite free or finite flat, we can deduce that the support of M is the union of some irreducible components of $\mathrm{Spec}A$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You answer the free and flat case yourself. For Cohen-Macaulay this is wrong. Consider $A = k[x,y]$ where $k$ is a field. Then $M = k[x,y] / (x) \cong k[y]$ is Cohen-Macaulay, but has as support the proper closed subset $V(x) \subsetneq \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y] = \mathbb A^2$, which is the $y$-axis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I only assume that $M$ is finite flat over $A$, I do not know if $\mathrm{Supp}M$ is the union of some irreducible components of $\mathrm{Spec}A$.

Comment: @Jean Sorry, I misread your question. I'll try to improve my answer.